# How does the actual tattoo on Sasuke's shoulder should look?

Tags: naruto

Next month I am going to have the Sasuke's curse mark tattoo, but I am not sure how exactly does it look because I find two types on Google Images as below:

1. [image: tattoo from anime]
2. [image: tattoo from manga?]

The first one is the one I took from the anime series, and the second one is I guess from the manga series. Although I will ask my tattoo artist to trace it well, if someone could give a clear picture that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**The first one is correct**

As you can se on the second image, theres a name on the bottom left corner. The second image is a fan-drawing and not from the anime/manga. The mark is on the left shoulder.

[image: 1. The moment when he got the mark]

[image: The moment, when Kakashi was sealing it]

[image: The actual sealed mark]

1. The moment when he got the mark
2. The moment, when Kakashi was sealing it
3. The actual sealed mark